# Problemas al usar el navigator cannot property 'push' of unedefined

Tags: react-native

Al intentar darle al button aceptar para pasar a una ventana de navigation a traves de los navegadores me arroja el error cannot property 'push' of unedefined el cual se refiere a las siguientes lineas de codigo.

```
aceptar(){
      this.props.navigator.push ({
      title: 'Dashboard',
      name: 'Dashboard',
      passProps:{}
});
}
```

Comment: Voto negativo. Con lo fácil que es ir quitándolas hasta que deje de dar el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estás pasando el objeto `navigator` a tu componente a través de `props`

```
<MiEscena navigator={miNavigatorEnElComponenteSuperior} />
```